# Why does numpy.r_ sometimes include endpoints when constructing arrays, and sometimes not?

Tags: python, numpy

numpy.r_ can be use to build arrays quickly from slice notation. However, the following example appears to demonstrate inconsistent behavior:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> a = np.r_[0.1 : 0.3 : 0.1]
>>> a
array([0.1, 0.2])
```

Endpoint of the slice 0.3 not included - as expected.

```
>>> b = np.r_[0.1 : 0.4 : 0.1]
>>> b
array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])
```

Endpoint of the slice 0.4 included!

There does not appear to be an explanation for this behavior in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html).

Comment: Use a complex `step`, which uses `linspace` and better end point control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `c` is real, `numpy.r_[a:b:c]` is equivalent to `numpy.arange(a, b, c)`. Using floats here is a bad idea, as documented in the [`numpy.arange` docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) - the length may be wrong, because a length calculation based on floating-point values is subject to floating-point rounding error, and the step itself may suffer precision loss due to implementation details of how NumPy handles the step internally.

As suggested in the `numpy.arange` docs, you should use `numpy.linspace` instead. `numpy.linspace` takes an element count as an integer, instead of taking a step:

```
b = numpy.linspace(0.1, 0.4, num=3, endpoint=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. From this answer it seems that using `numpy.r_` and/or `numpy.arange` to generate float ranges is so unreliable that there is not even a justifiable use case for the implementation. Why is it even a feature? Also, similar operations seem to work fine in languages like Julia and MATLAB. Why such an unreliable implementation in numpy?

Comment: "Why is it even a feature?" - historical reasons, probably. I don't know what MATLAB does, but Julia [tries to get fancy with high-precision arithmetic](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/23194) and [still doesn't always do what someone unaware of floating-point rounding issues would expect](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/33677). If you want reliable results in Julia, you should use `range(start, stop, length=length)`.

Comment: Thanks. Really thorough answer and appreciated the links to the gitub issue/pr. It seems that [MATLAB works from both ends to mitigate the error accumulation](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/217673-issues-with-the-colon-operator). This will still of course be a problem for the precision of intermediate values, but at least guarantees the user gets the right endpoint...

Answer (score 0):

because in python real numbers are not always rounded, as in your example horizontal step 0.2+0.1 is close to 0.300000000000004 and the result will be wrong.
I would use this way but it seems to be more complicated:

```
from decimal import *
import numpy as np
getcontext().prec = 6 # setting new values for precision, rounding, or enabled traps
b = Decimal(2)/Decimal(5) # 0.4
a = Decimal(1)/Decimal(10) # 0.1
print(np.r_[a: b : a])
```